# How do I convert an object of Class B to Class C, if both Class B and C are derived of Class A in C++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, type-conversion

I have a base class called "Customer", and 2 derived classes "RegularAccount" and "VipAccount".

Now, I want to implement a "promote" member method, that allows RegularAccount to be promoted to VipAccount if it meets some condition.

How can I do this in C++? I tried to call a constructor inside the "promote" method of RegularAccount but was unable to do so. Is there a way to copy all data from RegularAccount's object to VipAccount's object in a member function of RegularAccount?

Here is the structure of my RegularAccount class:

```
class RegularAccount : public Customer {
private:

public:
  // Constructors && Destructors
  RegularAccount();
  RegularAccount(string id, string name, string address, string phoneNumber, int numberOfRental);
  ~RegularAccount();

  // Member functions
  void rentItem(const string itemName);

  void returnItem(const string itemName);

  void details();

  void showRentalList();

  void promote();

};
```

VipAccount class:

```
class VipAccount : public Customer {
private:
  int rewardPoints;
  int freeRentItemAwarded;


public:
  // Constructors
  VipAccount();

  VipAccount(string id, string name, string address, string phoneNumber, int numberOfRental);

  // Member functions
  void rentItem(const string itemName);

  void returnItem(const string itemName);

  void checkRewardPoints();

  void details();

  void showRentalList();

  void promote();

};
```

Comment: please put minimal reproducable example. What is definition of VipAccount ?

Comment: I am a student who is learning C and C++ at the same time. I am very new to pointers and Inheritance concepts.

Comment: @StPiere Sorry, I just put in the header for VipAccount class.

Comment: The problem here is that if you ask 10 C++ developers "what is the best way to do <X>" you will get 11 different answers. Opinion-based questions are, unfortunately, off-topic for stackoverflow.com

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I intended to get a solution for this. But I know there are many solutions so that was why I put "What are the best ways?". Anyway, I changed this to "How can I do this...".

Comment: There's only one way to do this in C++: create a new object C. There's only one way to create objects in C++, whether they are new object or somehow based, in some form, on some other object. The fact that they might have the same superclass is completely immaterial. It does not make any difference whatsoever.

Comment: The way I would implement this is to have a state flag in the class, `enum class Status { regular, vip };` and a `Status _status;` member variable.  Or use another State interface member variable to a concrete State implementation that can be set or reset as needed, following the [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

Comment: Why does `RegularAccount` have a destructor?

Answer (score 1):

Derive VipAccount from RegularAccount, makes sense cause Vip should have everything Regular has. Write a constructor for VipAccount which accepts an instance of RegularAccount as argument. In constructor pass the argument to the base class RegularAccount. To promote ,create an instance of VipAccount with RegularAccount as argument, delete instance of RegularAccount afterwards